# Did my python subprocess break something?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm learning python and playing with the subprocess module. After reading several different tutorials and descriptions of how to use the module, my understanding was still not incredibly solid so I started working up some simple code to test the various functions and see how everything worked.

I wanted to see how it might behave if I tried to start the same process multiple times, using this code:

```
import subprocess

def tpltest(x):
    while x > 0:
        try:
            subprocess.Popen('wordgrinder')
        except:
            print 'something broke!'
        x -= 1

x = raw_input('how many?')
tpltest(x)
```

When I ran this in my terminal, wordgrinder (terminal word processor) opened normally, but then the cursor advanced down the screen at a rate of about one line per second. It appeared to be movement only, rather than any characters being added to the blank file onscreen. I pressed ctrl+c to see if a wordgrinder remained after closing the first instance and was met with my regular command line prompt, but the cursor continued to scroll. I ran top and did not see extra wordgrinder instances open, but the cursor continued scrolling.

Then I discovered the oddest part. If I rolled my mouse scroll wheel up in the window, chunks of text appeared over the window's contents. Some of the chunks were commands I had entered in the console over the past week, some of them were commands I had entered in my python shell but not the regular terminal, and some of the text was my WiFi security information, including the plaintext WPA2 password for my network. Scrolling the mousewheel down had no effect but scrolling up would overwrite a few lines with new text, seemingly from other random places in my system. After closing the terminal window and opening a new one, things were back to normal.

I'm running Debian 8 64bit with XFCE and using the default terminal emulator.

***What did my code do, and why?***

Comment: 1- your code  starts at most one `subprocess` (`x` is a string and therefore `x -= 1` should raise TypeError) 2- `wordgrinder` probably hasn't shutdown properly on Ctrl+C. Typing `reset` in the terminal might help.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation that I can offer is that what subprocess does is to run a background process. Additionally, wordgrinder is a program that takes full control of the terminal session by capturing input from the keyboard (stdin) and controlling the command-line (stdout) in a very particular way.

When you ran wordgrinder in the background through your script, it caused some funky things to happen. That's pretty crazy that your WiFi password ended up getting displayed from your experiment.